# When did hashem tell the world enough?

Tags: midrash

When did Hashem tell the world enough? In this song by [Yaakov Shwekey](http://yaakovshwekey.com) the lyrics say "He who told his world enough, Can surely tell our problems-Enough! There will be happiness free of troubles-My father-just say ENOUGH!!". Under the lyrics the source is Midrash Tanchumah.
[image: On the left - lyrics for the song Smachot]

Comment: Check out Chagigah 12a

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @DoubleAA. Looked up Chagigah 12a.
[image]

https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.11b-12a?lang=bi

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3429